# How to get class/method/attribute info in Android XML file?

Tags: android, xml, intellij-idea

When I am in a Java class file, I can get context info of a certain method/attribute/etc. (in IntelliJ, this shortcut is Ctrl+Q), which is basically a short help file describing what that element does. Look at the image 1.

[image]
But when I am in an XML file, I cannot get any contextual info on any element. Look at the image 2.

[image]

How should I enable it? Do I have to download some additional Android doc (javadoc?) file?

Comment: What info do you expect to see for the XML style?

Comment: Description of that style. Is this possible?

Comment: Not now. Where IDEA should look to extract this description?

Comment: My point exactly. Maybe inside some kind of javadoc... ?!

Comment: Or the problem is because the XML attributes are treated as strings (inside double qoute marks)... Just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CrazyCoder suggested, there is no way to get such contextual info because of the lack of sources to fetch such info from. Until better times...

Answer (score 1):

For Android code support in Eclipse, you might want to checkout http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/new-editing-features-in-eclipse-plug-in.html.

In particular :

XML editing has been improved with new quick fixes, code completion in more file types and many “go to declaration” enhancements.

Comment: Cool. Unfortunately I use IntelliJ, but I'll check this new feature in Eclipse as well.

Answer (score 0):

> basically a short help file describing what that element does

FYI: It's called Javadoc.

For the xml:
Go to Window, Show View, Other, General, Properties.
Then, when you have opened an Android xml, you can switch to the Graphical Layout. Clicking on an element will show you it's properties in the property view. Hovering over the elements there at least will give you contextual information.

Comment: Thanks but this way's too complicated. That's why contextual info was invented on the first place ;).